# why registering incoming call BroadCastReceiver in manifest do not work?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I register a BroadCastReceiver in my manifest as bellow :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.droid.arghaman.test_app">

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<activity
    android:name="com.droid.arghaman.test_app.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<receiver
    android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:label="StartServiceAtBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <!--action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action-->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<service android:name="LocationNotifierService"></service>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

but my BroadCastReceiver never fired up when my phone is ringing. this is my BroadCastReceiver code:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends MyBroadcastReceiver {
Context ctx;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ctx = context;
    try {
        // TELEPHONY MANAGER class object to register one listner
        TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) context
               .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        //Create Listner
        MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();

        // Register listener for LISTEN_CALL_STATE
        tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Phone Receive Error", " " + e);
    }

}

private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        Log.d("MyPhoneListener",state+"   incoming no:"+incomingNumber);

        if (state == 1) {

            String msg = "New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : "+incomingNumber;
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctx, msg, duration);
            toast.show();

        }
    }
}
}
```

but when I register my BroadCastReceiver by this code snippet in side my first activity it work perfectly:

```
 IntentFilter filter= new IntentFilter();
 filter.addAction(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING);
 filter.addAction(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
 MyBroadcastReceiver receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver ();
 this.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

is there any version conflict or deprecation in android or this is my mistake?

Comment: there is no BroadcastReceiver in `manifest` like `MyBroadcastReceiver `

Comment: Change BootBroadcastReceiver with MyBroadcastReceiver in the manifest .

Comment: it was my typo in my question i change it... please assume in real word all classes and refrence are correct

Comment: some broadcastReceivers can't be triggered by being declared in the manifest, they have to be registered in code. This is made because of security about theat user has to at least start the application before it can register dangerous receivers (as I understand)

Comment: which of theme is so and how can find their list? I see many sample in google which register incoming call receiver in manifest